# UMAP with Tensorboard projector

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Is there a possibility to use [UMAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) with [Tensorboard projector](https://projector.tensorflow.org/). Indeed, at the moment, we can only use PCA or T-SNE with it.

Alternatively, is there a Python library that would allow generating interactive plots such as Tensorboard's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the online version of the [Tensorflow Projector](https://projector.tensorflow.org/) does now include [UMAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I guess they have added that feature recently as I was using the projector quite some times lately and until last week they only provided PCA, TSNE or a custom visualization in the online version. But now it is there, give it a try.

[Tensorflow Projector with UMAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR6xz.png)

I didn't find a Python library to create such interactive visualizations as tensorboards but if you'd like to try a JavaScript Version you could start with this [making-an-interactive-umap-visualization-of-the-mnist-data-set](https://blog.fastforwardlabs.com/2019/01/29/making-an-interactive-umap-visualization-of-the-mnist-data-set.html) blog post. Here is the showcase: [Online UMAP Explorer with three.js](https://grantcuster.github.io/umap-explorer/)